# platform list does not work in latest phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova

% phonegap version
3.5.0-0.20.10

This was just installed with npm

% npm --version
1.4.21

So the list command gives this

```
% phonegap platform list
   [error] 'platform list' is not a phonegap command. See 'phonegap help'
```

Then,

```
% phonegap platform help

Usage: phonegap platform [command]

Description:

  Update a platform to the latest version.

Commands:

  update <platform>    update platform to the latest version

Examples:

  $ phonegap platform update android
```

Ok, so maybe the "list" command got deprecated. Checking:

```
% phonegap platform update ios
[phonegap] npm
[phonegap] phonegap
[phonegap] module
[phonegap] updating iOS platform using PhoneGap CLI version 3.5.0-0.20.10
{ [CordovaError: Platform "ios" is not installed. See `cordova platform list`.]
  name: 'CordovaError',
  message: 'Platform "ios" is not installed. See `cordova platform list`.' }
   [error] Platform "ios" is not installed. See `cordova platform list`.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly mentioned in the bottom which command you need to use for this

`cordova platform list`

Comment: PhoneGap is now a an extension of cordova. The PhoneGap CLI only performs commands that cordova does not have. Anything related to local building, you should use cordova in lieu of phonegap, as this answer points out.

Comment: Ah ok I will try that out - at some point after some reading and playing it looked like phonegap alone worked out better than cordova (perhaps due to some strange things during installation) and so I've gotten used to just phonegap (as recent as 3.3 I think).